# AngularJS view not updating on model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to figure out how Angular works and am having trouble getting my view to update when the model changes..

HTML

```
<div ng-app="test">  
        <p ng-controller="TestCtrl">  
            {{testValue}}  
        </p>  
    </div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

    app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.testValue = 0;

        setInterval(function() {
            console.log($scope.testValue++);
        }, 500);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N2G7z/

any ideas?

Comment: apart from below answer if you still want to  use settimeout you have to use scope.$apply()

Comment: $scope.$apply() is what i need. the model in the project i'm working on is updated after user interaction. i'm not actually using a timeout or an interval but it's good to know how to use them with angular in the future.
thanks for the answers!

Comment: Here is an interesting article in which you will more informations about the $digest cycles http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 126, accepted):

As Ajay beniwal mentioned above you need to use Apply to start digestion.

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.testValue = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log($scope.testValue++);
        $scope.$apply() 
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Diego Vieira's answer is better. Rule of thumb would be: whenever possible, use Angular's providers/services, they do the apply by themselves.

Comment: At time I wrote that comment there were no any $intervals 
Its just wrapper to setInterval btw.
also its not so save how it looks: Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: that's a hack, angular has its own timers, $interval should be used instead to update watchers

Comment: Read my comments above

Comment: This method is not safe to use because, it will continue to update model for the given interval...

Answer (score 37):

Just use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Here is your code modified.
http://plnkr.co/edit/m7psQ5rwx4w1yAwAFdyr?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
   $scope.testValue = 0;

    $interval(function() {
        $scope.testValue++;
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 30):

`setTimout` executes outside of angular.  You need to use `$timeout` service for this to work:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

    app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
       $scope.testValue = 0;

        $timeout(function() {
            console.log($scope.testValue++);
        }, 500);
    });
```

The reason is that two-way binding in angular uses dirty checking.  [This is a good article](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/) to read about angular's dirty checking.  `$scope.$apply()` kicks off a `$digest` cycle.  This will apply the binding.  `$timeout` handles the `$apply` for you so it is the recommended service to use when using timeouts.

Essentially, binding happens during the `$digest` cycle (if the value is seen to be different).

Answer (score 8):

Do not use  `$scope.$apply()` angular already uses it and it can result in this error

> $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress

if you use twice, use `$timeout` or interval