# View not getting updated while updating the $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, angular-ngmodel

Here I tried out a code that just simply incremetns the calendar month value by 1, the code is working fine reflected by the values in console, but the view doesn't get updated. I can't get the point where I'm going wrong. Please Advise as I am not much familliar to angulars behaviour. Intention is to increment the Month on right arrow click as eg January 2015 and decrement the value on left arrow click. The code is working fine, but for the view just never updates.

**View:**

```
<div class="ctr-align btm-bdr"><a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/redarrow_bac.png" align="absmiddle" width="24" height="32" alt="" ng-click="decrMonth()"></a> &nbsp; {{month}} {{year}} &nbsp; <a href="javascript:;" ><img src="images/redarrow.png" align="absmiddle" width="24" height="32" alt="" ng-click="incrMonth()"></a></div>
```

**{{month}} {{year}}** is the UI part which doesn't get updated even if the **$scope.month** and the **$scope.year** gets updated in the js.

**UI**
[image]

**Controller**

```
//---------------------------- Loading next month on the arrows pressed ----------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    $scope.initJobsController           = function(){
        if(!UserServices.isLoggedIn()){
            HeaderService.setHeader(header_config.HEADER_LOGIN);
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        else{
            HeaderService.hideHeader();
            $scope.dateToday = new Date();
            $scope.setCalendarMonthHead($scope.dateToday);
            $scope.jobsLoadingTitle      = msg_config.JOBS_LOADING;
            $scope.jobsLoading           = true;
            JobsServices.getMyJobList($scope.startIndex);
            var timer= $timeout(function(){
                $scope.replaceFont();
            },0.5)
        }
    };
    // Description : Function that increments the month by 1
    $scope.incrMonth                    = function(){
        $scope.dateToday.setMonth($scope.dateToday.getMonth() + 1);
        $scope.setCalendarMonthHead($scope.dateToday);
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    // Description : Function that decrement the month by 1
    $scope.decrMonth                    = function(){
        $scope.dateToday.setMonth($scope.dateToday.getMonth() - 1);
        $scope.setCalendarMonthHead($scope.dateToday);
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    // Description : Function that decrement the month by 1
    $scope.setCalendarMonthHead         = function(date){
        var monthNames   = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
        $scope.month      = monthNames[$scope.dateToday.getMonth()];
        $scope.year       = $scope.dateToday.getFullYear();
        // alert($scope.month + " " + $scope.year);
    };
```

Even the **$scope.$apply();** doesn't seem to work, tried all possiblities as mentioned here [AngularJS view not updating on model change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070077/angularjs-view-not-updating-on-model-change), http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html, [angular.js: model update doesn't trigger view update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185753/angular-js-model-update-doesnt-trigger-view-update) as they all revolve around the use of **$scope.$apply()** .

Comment: what is `$scope.dateToday` ?

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha have included the code, actually it was the initialization part of the view

Comment: its working , please check http://plnkr.co/edit/qDwTkHYmdu24fTQtVWuO?p=preview

Comment: It is working in plunker, but not in the browser, says: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress, which means $scope.$apply needs to be delayed.

Comment: remove two `$scope.$apply` s they are not needed at there. i updated the plunker also

Comment: Thanks pal, but I had started off with no $scope.$apply().... :P, as it failed to reflect the changes, i had no other options but to include it

Comment: is it working now ? or please create a plunker demonstrating ur problem :)

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha, the ng-model, $scope, do they apply only for <input> tags? I doubt it because, it seems a nested div hierarchy given by our designer here... <div><a><img></a> &nbsp; {{month}} {{year}} &nbsp; <a ><img></a></div> Is that the reason it's not getting it? I tested it out in Chrome, Fire fox